# Matching wildcard arrays in Excel or R

Tags: excel

I'm trying to match the A column with any values in B but I can't figure out the correct formula to get the Match results.
The values in A match if B has a wildcard value that corresponds.

```
A             B     Match
1             2     NO
2_1           3     YES
3             13    YES
3_1           14    YES
3_2                 YES
9                   NO
12                  NO
14                  YES
14_3                YES
16                  NO
19                  NO
20                  NO
```

I've tried to add a wildcard to the B array but this does not work as I intended

```
C2=MATCH(A2,B2:B5&"*")=#VALUE!
```

Comment: It's unclear what the intended result should be. Is `Match` in the excerpt you've produced intended? Should we be looking for `Seeking` in `Available`?

Comment: @Hugh: I've changed the confusing field headers. The Match column is the intended result. I'm looking for A in B, where B can be supplemented with a wildcard.

Answer (score 3):

Using R, and including the `Match` column from your data.

You want rows where the value of `A` occurs anywhere in the column `B`?

```
> x[x$A %in% x$B,]
   A  B Match
3  3 13   YES
8 14 NA   YES
```

It looks like you might want to match everything before the `_`:

```
> with(x, x[sub('_.*', '', A) %in% B,])
     A  B Match
2  2_1  3   YES
3    3 13   YES
4  3_1 14   YES
5  3_2 NA   YES
8   14 NA   YES
9 14_3 NA   YES
```